# Grails 2.5.0 not using my lib/ jars when deployed to tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails

I had to compile a custom version of the flying saucer jars used by the rendering plugin to get around a problem with rendering and bootstrap css. It works fine locally...I can render a gsp to PDF. If I don't include my custom jars in the lib directory, I get the following error:

```
com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(C)[I. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [invoiceAll] of controller [myapp.ReportsController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(C)[I
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver$FontDescription.setMetricDefaults(ITextFontResolver.java:679)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver$FontDescription.<init>(ITextFontResolver.java:610)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.addCourier(ITextFontResolver.java:410)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.createInitialFontMap(ITextFontResolver.java:390)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.<init>(ITextFontResolver.java:52)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:115)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:102)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.pdf.PdfRenderingService.doRender(PdfRenderingService.groovy:34)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:43)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:37)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:35)
    at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:65)
    at RenderingGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(RenderingGrailsPlugin.groovy:59)
    at myapp.ReportsController.invoiceAll(ReportsController.groovy:46)
    ... 8 more
```

So, doing this locally works fine. lsof shows my jars in use by the grails java process:

```
java    26951 myuser  mem    REG             253,14    105122  531524 /home/myuser/sworkspace/groovy/tls_billing/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java    26951 myuser  mem    REG             253,14   1106329  528159 /home/myuser/sworkspace/groovy/tls_billing/lib/flying-saucer-core-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java    26951 myuser  mem    REG             253,14    105172  531525 /home/myuser/sworkspace/groovy/tls_billing/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java    26951 myuser   68r   REG             253,14    105172  531525 /home/myuser/sworkspace/groovy/tls_billing/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java    26951 myuser   69r   REG             253,14   1106329  528159 /home/myuser/sworkspace/groovy/tls_billing/lib/flying-saucer-core-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java    26951 myuser   75r   REG             253,14    105122  531524 /home/myuser/sworkspace/groovy/tls_billing/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.1-myapp.jar
```

Just to be safe, I also sha1sum'd the jars locally:

```
2c135a987892978d670cd73e789fa3337d50e7ff  lib/flying-saucer-core-9.0.1-myapp.jar
b774052563a12fc212370a1c1a8a71ea5b8c0e87  lib/flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.1-myapp.jar
64c01c5f3425b0723b0d2e4a034fe9f23e3e1720  lib/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.0.1-myapp.jar
```

So, after "grails war" and then deploying to a remote Tomcat server, I get the following error:

```
2015-07-15 16:56:20,221 [http-bio-80-exec-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(C)[I
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver$FontDescription.setMetricDefaults(ITextFontResolver.java:679)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver$FontDescription.<init>(ITextFontResolver.java:610)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.addCourier(ITextFontResolver.java:410)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.createInitialFontMap(ITextFontResolver.java:390)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.<init>(ITextFontResolver.java:52)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:115)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:102)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.pdf.PdfRenderingService.doRender(PdfRenderingService.groovy:34)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:43)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:37)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:35)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:65)
        at RenderingGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(RenderingGrailsPlugin.groovy:59)
        at myapp.ReportsController.invoiceAll(ReportsController.groovy:46)
        ... 8 more
2015-07-15 16:56:20,221 [http-bio-80-exec-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(C)[I
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver$FontDescription.setMetricDefaults(ITextFontResolver.java:679)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver$FontDescription.<init>(ITextFontResolver.java:610)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.addCourier(ITextFontResolver.java:410)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.createInitialFontMap(ITextFontResolver.java:390)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.<init>(ITextFontResolver.java:52)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:115)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:102)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.pdf.PdfRenderingService.doRender(PdfRenderingService.groovy:34)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:43)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:37)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:35)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:65)
        at RenderingGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(RenderingGrailsPlugin.groovy:59)
        at myapp.ReportsController.invoiceAll(ReportsController.groovy:46)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-07-15 16:56:20,221 [http-bio-80-exec-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [invoiceAll] of controller [myapp.ReportsController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.getCharBBox(C)[I
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver$FontDescription.setMetricDefaults(ITextFontResolver.java:679)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver$FontDescription.<init>(ITextFontResolver.java:610)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.addCourier(ITextFontResolver.java:410)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.createInitialFontMap(ITextFontResolver.java:390)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.<init>(ITextFontResolver.java:52)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:115)
        at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:102)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.pdf.PdfRenderingService.doRender(PdfRenderingService.groovy:34)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:43)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:37)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:35)
        at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.render(RenderingService.groovy:65)
        at RenderingGrailsPlugin$_closure3.doCall(RenderingGrailsPlugin.groovy:59)
        at myapp.ReportsController.invoiceAll(ReportsController.groovy:46)
        ... 8 more
```

Just to be certain, I cd'd into /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib (where my app is deployed) and ran:

```
$ sha1sum flying-saucer-*
2c135a987892978d670cd73e789fa3337d50e7ff  flying-saucer-core-9.0.1-myapp.jar
b774052563a12fc212370a1c1a8a71ea5b8c0e87  flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.1-myapp.jar
64c01c5f3425b0723b0d2e4a034fe9f23e3e1720  flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.0.1-myapp.jar
```

Matches up. However, is the app actually holding file handles open to the jars?

At first, after I hadn't loaded the URL for a bit, it didn't appear to be:

```
$ sudo lsof | grep flying | wc -l 
0
```

I assume Tomcat spins down threads though, because after visiting the URL which uses the jar (and causes the exception) again, I get hits:

```
$ sudo lsof | grep flying

F/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24542        root  mem       REG              254,0  1106329     268857 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-core-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24542        root  mem       REG              254,0   105122     268824 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24542        root   93r      REG              254,0  1106329     268857 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-core-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24542        root   94r      REG              254,0   105122     268824 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24542        root   95r      REG              254,0   105172     268734 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24559        root  mem       REG              254,0   105172     268734 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24559        root  mem       REG              254,0  1106329     268857 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-core-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24559        root  mem       REG              254,0   105122     268824 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24559        root   93r      REG              254,0  1106329     268857 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-core-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24559        root   94r      REG              254,0   105122     268824 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24559        root   95r      REG              254,0   105172     268734 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24629        root  mem       REG              254,0   105172     268734 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24629        root  mem       REG              254,0  1106329     268857 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-core-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24629        root  mem       REG              254,0   105122     268824 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24629        root   93r      REG              254,0  1106329     268857 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-core-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24629        root   94r      REG              254,0   105122     268824 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.1-myapp.jar
java      24487 24629        root   95r      REG              254,0   105172     268734 /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.61/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/flying-saucer-pdf-itext5-9.0.1-myapp.jar
...snip...

$ lsof | grep flyingsaucer | wc -l
228
```

So, the jars are loaded, but the app is still unable to find my custom compiled jars which contain the missing method.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Could the "original" versions of those jars be on the classpath, so it might load both, but be using the original... which is missing that class: https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/issues/detail?id=126   Maybe check out all the jars deployed as part of the app, and see if the original ones are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a classpath conflict. When starting the Tomcat container try add `-verbose` to your JVM settings:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-verbose"
```

Then from the output check which JAR the `com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont` is loaded from and verify it is the correct one. This will help you debug the situation.

Comment: It appears you are correct. My patched flyingsaucer libs require itext 2.1.7, but the grails rendering plugin requires itext 2.1.7, according to the dependency report. What's the best way to get around this? Is my only option to fork the rendering plugin and recompile with 2.7.0?

Comment: Wow...talk about getting version numbers wrong. Sorry. I meant my patched libs require 2.1.7, but the rendering plugin requires 2.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the exactly same problem, but seems to be ok in the *.9.0.7 version of flying-saucer.

The problem is that the signature of the *BaseFont.getCharBBox()* was changed since **itext-2.1.2**:

```
// from
public int[] getCharBBox(char c) 

// to
public int[] getCharBBox(int c)
```

[]'s